# What happened to Sokka's sword after the invasion?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender, the-legend-of-korra

What happened to Sokka's sword after the invasion in *Avatar: The last Airbender*? Is it in one of the *Avatar* comics? Just curious.

[image: Sokka wielding his metorite iron sword]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sokka loses his trusty Jian 劍 meteorite iron [sword](https://avatar.fandom.com/wiki/Sokka%27s_sword#cite_note-SM-1) while knocking out two firebenders during "[Sozin's Comet : Part 4](https://avatar.fandom.com/wiki/Sozin%27s_Comet,_Part_4:_Avatar_Aang)" as a necessary trade-off to save his and Toph's life.

It falls into the forest and we don't see it again in the episode.

> A firebender comes out of the ship and fires at Sokka and Toph. They
> fall of the side and Sokka uses his sword in an attempt to stop the
> fall. They fall and land on a platform, breaking Sokka's leg and his
> sword landing just in front of him. Toph falls off and Sokka holds
> onto her hand.
>
> **Sokka** [In pain.] *My leg! Hang on Toph!*
>
> **Toph**  *Aye, aye, Captain.* Two firebenders come out on the platforms next to them. One of them is about to shoot them off, but
>
> Sokka throws his boomerang at him. He kicks his sword in to his hand
> and throws it at the other one's platform.
>
> **Sokka** [Sadly.] *Bye, space sword.*

Although there's no canon explanation for its recovery, you can clearly see on this officially licensed poster that Sokka does indeed recover his sword.

[image: Avatar Old Friends New Friends poster. In the "Old Friends" section, Sokka stands with his sword sheathed and his hand on Zuko's shoulder.]

Comment: How can you be sure it's the same sword?

Comment: Yeah, it could be a different sword though?

Comment: @svick it could be. The handle/grip is the same though and it appears to be about the same length.

Comment: Good question. I'd like to know the answer, but I don't think there is one. That sword in the image above could be a copy modelled on the original space-sword. I think its likely that the first one fell to earth and was never found ... especially if it broke into pieces.

Comment: I think it's very likely to be real. It looks the same and Sokka would likely remember where he'd dropped it. Then it's just a matter of searching.

Comment: an Earth Bender like Toph could probably "see" the sword given she sees the world in a different way so she and Sokka proably one day went back for it, Toph proably even suggested it to pay back Sokka for saving her life (or when on her own)